# BobyQA alters the starting point and computes sub-optimal result?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, apache-commons-math

I'm trying out the Apache Commons Math's BobyQA algorithm for bound non linear optimization.

I know the optimum (found it using matlab's trust-range reflective algorithm) and I'm confused about the following:

I set BobyQA's starting point to optimal and the first point it evaluates is NOT the starting point I've assigned, but altered suboptimal starting point (it changes the first parameter). 
And, further more, it does not find the minimum.

Example (least squares for optimal - starting point):

> lsq(optimal) = 5.526374615719567E9 for [1.0141E-7, 81.15, 119.03,
>   32.0, 0.36652, 4.317, 8.5167, 17.3, 16.470001, 100.13, 11.242, 29.042, 18.871, 29.92, 36.147, 87.826, 21.287]

And then I run BobyQA with that starting point, and in the first iteration it modifies the first parameter (from 1.0141E-7 to 0.026117):

> lsq(1) = 1.7374657025186486E19 for [0.02611793333333286, 81.15,
>   119.03, 32.0, 0.36652, 4.317, 8.5167, 17.3, 16.496117933333334, 100.13, 11.223249066666666, 29.042, 18.871, 29.92, 36.147, 87.826, 21.287]

and finally it reaches the suboptimal solution at:

> lsq(274) = 5.526621213826441E9 for [1.0115737485704292E-7,
>   81.14883064785045, 119.02964714352679, 32.00103316109643, 0.36615877961432247, 4.317235538618653, 8.516900515414736, 17.293306813210172, 16.496079045753113, 100.12980568809833, 11.22341107874299, 29.042103684597272, 18.870381140825014, 29.919895452015545, 36.14745517499619, 87.82657624240575, 21.288471755903668]

where 5.5266E9 is bigger than 5.5263E9.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: BOBYQA will take search steps proportional to the RHO parameter, which will start at RHOBEG and finish at around RHOEND. If you start at approximately optimum, BOBYQA is likely to take a rather big step away from that point, and might not be able to return as RHO decreases. What happens if you **do not** start at (near) optimum?

Comment: If i start from a suboptimum I reach a better, but also a suboptimal solution.
In numbers, I start from the 
lsq = 5.62E9
and reach a better lsq =5.58E9
but still worse than 
lsq(optimal) = 5.52E9.

Comment: What RHOBEG and RHOEND values are you using? If your starting point is close to the optimum, you could start with a smaller RHOBEG than default, and also try to reduce RHOEND for "longer" convergence.

Comment: I've varied the DEFAULT_INITIAL_RADIUS = 10.0; and DEFAULT_STOPPING_RADIUS = 1E-8; from 10 to 1 and from 1E-8 to 1E-12 and I've got my iteration count up to 408 (from 274), but the numbers stay pretty much the same :(.

Comment: I think that BOBYQA can be sensitive to variable scaling. Maybe you can try to rescale the largest variables during optimization?

Comment: Anders, thanks for your help, but I'm giving up for now on BobyQA, I'll try few others (Nelder-Mead and LM) and see how it goes.

Comment: May I ask how your research went, @igorludi ? I need to use an optimizer like these and BOBYQA seems promising. I've tried Nelder-Mead (prototype in Mathematica) and it works fine but I need several runs to get good values and the whole process is very slow. In my case variables have different scales so I may need to rescale/normalize them. Thanks!